# What is the most idiomatic choice in this case

Tags: future-tense

I am studying to become a pharmacist and I found a summer job in a pharmacy, I have just signed my contract

Shall I say

I **am working** for  the next two months. I **begin** 1st july and **finish** 1st september

I **am going to**  work the next two months .I **am beginning** 1st july and **finishing**  1st september

I think both are ok but the first seems to me a bit better

Comment: They all sound okay to me.  Personally I would say: I'll be working for the next two months.  I'll begin July 1st and finish September 1st.

Comment: One quibble on your second sentence: Remove the word "for". It should be just "I **am going to** work ... "

Comment: Also, months are always Capitalized.